# Boolean majority function

Tags: multiplexer, digital-logic

[image]

In this picture is an example of a boolean majority function (may be a bad example) So the rule says that the result or an output of a majority logic function would be a selection of majority inputs, so if there are 3 inputs, then 1 would become result if we input at least two 1's and 0 otherwise.

- Does this rule apply to any multiplexer?
- And does the output (result) depends on the logical gates being used in a boolean function?

Answer (score 3):

1) It shouldn't apply at all to a multiplexer if we're talking about the same thing.  A multiplexer is (to me) a device that has many inputs and one output and uses selection pins to tell it which input should be routed to the output.

2) If the two sets of gates implement the same boolean function then it does not matter what gates are used in the implementation of that function.  There are multiple correct implementations (but not multiple correct implementations that minimize the number of gates used).

Comment: but at the same time we can use multiplexers to implement majority functions